# How to get predictions of test dataset from a trained model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have trained a neural network model in Tensorflow and saved the results of the training in a directory `trainlogs`.

Within `trainlogs`, there is a file `checkpoints`.

I think this is the file I must use to restore the trained parameters, but I am not sure how to use `tf.train.Saver()` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for it: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model.

A short snippet from this tutorial:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```